# Query Wiktionary only returns few words

Tags: api, mediawiki, wiktionary

I'm trying to get all spanish nouns from Wiktionary. I only need the titles, not the meaning of each word. Following other similar posts, I tried this query:

```
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Spanish_nouns&cmprop=title
```

But it only returns the 10 first:

```json
 {
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "continue": {
        "cmcontinue": "page|4142414345524f0a4142414345524f|1173240",
        "continue": "-||"
    },
    "query": {
        "categorymembers": [{
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "aaleniano"
            },
            {
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "ab."
            },
            {
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "ababa"
            },
            {
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "abab\u00e1bite"
            },
            {
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "ababol"
            },
            {
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "abac\u00e1"
            },
            {
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "abacalera"
            },
            {
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "abacalero"
            },
            {
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "abacera"
            },
            {
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "abacer\u00eda"
            }
        ]
    }
 }
```

What should I do to get all the noun title's from A to Z?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to forward the value of `cmcontinue` to the next call as query parameter, in your case it would be  `cmcontinue=page|4142414345524f0a4142414345524f|1173240` :

```
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Spanish_nouns&cmprop=title&cmcontinue=page|4142414345524f0a4142414345524f|1173240
```

Check [the api result](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Spanish_nouns&cmprop=title&cmcontinue=page%7C4142414345524f0a4142414345524f%7C1173240)

Also, from [this doc](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Lists), you can set `cmlimit=max` in order to get the maximum result you can get for a single call. So the first call would be :

```
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Spanish_nouns&cmprop=title&cmlimit=max
```

Then, using `cmcontinue`:

```
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Spanish_nouns&cmprop=title&cmlimit=max&cmcontinue=page|41434943414c41445552410a41434943414c4144555241|4536720
```